# Java - Duplicate method for taking in a string in a different format

Tags: java, date

Currently  working on a small Java date class program.

Okay, so I have a two constructors which take in dates as either parameters (e.g. 28, 12, 1995), and the other constructor as parsing a string (e.g. "25-4-2009") to find and validate the values. I wish to create another constructor which parses a string but in a different date format which on the surface seems pretty simple to do but I'm not sure as to what logic I should be following.

I have tried creating a new constructor with a different variable for the date string, so instead of "dateString", "dateString2" for instance, however Java doesn't like duplicate methods of the same type.

Should I be creating a new object type, so Date2 and using that to parse the new formatted date string? Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

N.B I am not using SimpleDateFormat, and sorry for the poor title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Do not create another Date2 class. One approach you can take is pass another argument in your constructor something like format. Based on what kind of String you pass in you can use the format argument to distinguish.

Here is a code snippet you can use.

Define an enum of supported formats.

```
public enum DateFormat {DD_MM_YYYY, MM_DD_YYYY};
```

Your constructor can look something like:

```
public MyDate(String date, DateFormat dateFormat) {
        switch (dateFormat) {
        case DD_MM_YYYY:
            // Do some parsing
            break;
        case MM_DD_YYYY:
            // Do some other passing
            break;
        default:
            // Handle invalid format
            break;
        }


    }
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Ooh wow! Thanks! I think that's exactly what I needed and kinda makes sense when you think about it. However there is a small issue which I'm not too sure how handle. On my tester program I have a simple constructor initialiser testing some sample variables. Since the constructor now takes two parameters, I have to pass in another, but what would I pass in?

Comment: Not sure what your tester program looks like. But I would guess your tester should pass one of the available enum values. If this exactly what you were looking for will you please accept it as answer :)

Comment: Here's a sample from the tester:

`...
Date d2 = new Date("29-12-2011");
System.out.println(d2);`

I tried passing in `Date d2 = new Date("05-02-2011", DD_MM_YYYY);` but it says the constructor is undefined in Eclipse. And yes I will! :)

Comment: If you can please post code of your tester program that will help suggest something.

Comment: Another link to the pastebin as the other one's gonna expire shortly :p http://pastebin.com/ZBs0z1iP

Comment: Can you upload full code of your tester with all the imports statements as well.

Comment: The class and the tester are in two different files. That's pretty much the tester program there excluding some other test cases which throw illegal argument exceptions. Importing this: `import java.util.Calendar;`

Answer (score 2):

As you know, it is impossible to have two constructors with same arguments type. In order to achieve desired, I'd recommend to create a flag (or maybe even `enum`) to indicate whether **format 1** or **format 2** is expected:

```
public ClassName(String date, boolean isDMY) {
    if (isDMY) {
        //date is like 25-4-2009, do parsing, saving, etc
    } else {
        //date is in another intended format, for example dd.mm.yyyy, do parsing...
    }
}
```

Note that this solution might be not the best one, but for the cases when you have only two possible formats, and your input is trusted (you're sure that constructor won't be invoked with strings like "20051110", for example), then it's ok IMO.

Answer (score 2):

You said that you aren't using `SimpleDateFormat`. It sounds like you should (unless this is an assignment that does not allow you to) and have your constructor call a method that can parse and format like so:

```
public Date(String date) {
    this.date = formatDate(String dateStr)
}
```

[here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-string-to-date-java/) is a great article on parsing dates.

Comment: Passing format pattern to constructor may also be a viable option.

Comment: I think he wanted not to use SimpeDateFormat may be for whatever reason project or just playing around.

Comment: @vkg is correct :) Thanks for the advice though, I'm sure someone else will find it useful and maybe me in the future!

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot write a parsing function that is able to determine the date format from the string dynamically, then you must pass extra information to the constructor signaling which date format it should be expecting by means of a second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a 2nd parameter for your String constructors?

```
MyDate(String date, char formatType)
```

You can use switch afterwards for parsing the date.

Comment: See the answer I posted above with a code snippet :)